# How to correctly add webmail config to Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, drupal

I'm trying to get Rainloop webmail up and running on a server that also hosts a Drupal site.

I'm using Perusio's Nginx config for Drupal ( https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx ).

I basically just need to add a location to handle the path to Rainloop so that the webmail will be accessible via https://example.com/rainloop.

I've added the following just outside the default location block in drupal.conf:

```
## Webmail handling
# serve static files
location ~ ^/rainloop/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
    rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    root /usr/share/nginx/;
    expires 30d;
}

location /rainloop {
    root /usr/share/nginx/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex_localtime on;
}

location ^~ /rainloop/data {
    deny all;
}
```

It's returning 404 even though the paths are correct.  I suspect it's to do with one or both of these locations at the end of the config:

```
location ^~ /index.php {
    if ( $args ~* "^q=(?<query_value>.*)" ) {
        rewrite ^/index.php$ $scheme://$host/?q=$query_value? last;
    }
    return 404;
}

## Any other attempt to access PHP files returns a 404.
location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

How do make an exception to these 404 rules for the rainloop directory?